# Connections to my server from non-local users are too slow

Tags: linux, bandwidth

Hi I have a CentOS server based in Chicago which doesn't seem to be providing fast bandwidth connections to non local users.

Is there anywhere on the server where this limitation may be configured?

I am relatively new to Linux so please forgive my ignorance on the matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no limitation appart you bandwidth / networking hardware .
You can speed up the system disablind all "reverse" checking option for APACHE / SSH / etc .

Generic Answer for quite generic question .